# ASP.NET MVC 3 ViewModels in a different project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

Is there anything from stopping you placing ViewModels in a different project?

I basically have a DataModel (Entity Framework) project, Data Access project (might merge this into the DataModel), Business Logic project and the ASP.NET MVC website. I want the Business Logic layer to return ViewModels so was wondering if these can be separate from the website code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely - you just need to reference the DLL in your MVC3 project and then reference those ViewModels in your strongly typed views.

Just make sure you declare

```
@model SeperateAssembly.ViewModelName
```

At the top of your views to make them strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : no

Long answer : no reason. It will make you have to think more about dependencies of project references and bits. You'll just have to be careful with the design when it comes to references etc.

Hope that helps.

Also, can help with unit testing :-)

Comment: Wait, I've been able to bind a view to a model contained in a different assembly before. Why are you saying no?

Comment: Because the question was "Is there anything from stopping you placing ViewModels in a different project?" and no there isn't :-)